# bash color echo : problem with '-n' option

Tags: bash, shell-script

here is my function to print color text:

```
cecho()
{
color=${1:-""}       #  defaults to original color if no color specified
colorreset="\E[0m"   #  back to black after function return
while read line; do
  echo -e "$color$line$colorreset"
done
return
}

$ blue="\E[34m"
$ echo "message" | cecho $blue
$ message  #  it appears in blue
```

but if I use -n option then nothing is printed:

```
$ echo -n "message" | cecho $blue
$
```

I need '-n' option because sometimes I print text with only a word with color in the whole line, like:

```
$ echo -n "this is "
$ echo "blue" | cecho $blue
```

Comment: Take a look at:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037?highlight=%28color%29

Comment: Be aware that the string you are proposing might be $term specific thus the answer here is not necessarily universal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is related to the fact that "read" requires an end of line to read the input.  Thus it will hang until some kind of input is entered (i.e. for ever).

Perhaps you should add '-n' option to cecho instead, that is.

```
$ echo "message | cecho -n $blue
```

then rewrite your function to check for the '`-n`', and then apply it to the `echo` inside of `cecho`.

Comment: To do that simply replace `color="${1:-""}"`   into `color="${*:-""}"`

Comment: This solution print in black '-n ' at the left of the text I want to print coloured.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer correctly states that `read` is not returning anything because there is no newline at the end of the data being read. You can avoid this by altering the `while` condition like this:

```
while read line || [ -n "$line" ];
```

Comment: this solution puts a trailing newline even when I use 'echo -n'.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, I'd do something as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

cecho()
{
color="${1:-""}"
colorreset=$(tput sgr0)    #  back to black after function return
while read line; do
 if [[ ! -n $color  ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "$line $colorreset"
 else
  printf '%s\n' "$1$line $colorreset" 
fi
done
return
}
cecho "$1"
```

[image]

Comment: what about printing text without the trailing newline? I tried your solution, using the -n option for echo makes the same problem as I had with my code.